# get a new dataframe by time window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a datetime as an index and some data:

```
datetime | x | y | z
```

I want to roll over the dataframe with `df.rolling("5S")`. So that I get a time window of 5 seconds and than applying some functions like mean, std, min or max.

My goal is to replace all rows in a time window with a new row which has the functions applied:

```
window | x_mean | x_std | ... | z_min | z_max
```

Is rolling capable of that? because at the moment I can just add a mean to each row and not summerize a time window in a new row.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling by definition does that, i.e. for every row, look back `5s` and do the aggregation. So you get the stats for every row.

Let's take an example:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.rand(1000)}, 
                  index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01', freq='S', periods=1000))
```

Then

```
df.rolling('5S').agg(['min','max', 'std'])
```

has 1000 rows, same as `df`.

I believe you are looking for `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5S')).agg(['min','max','std'])
```

which gives 200 rows, one for each block of `5s`.